# ¿Como puedo convertir jQuery a Javascript para utilizarlo en un componente de Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-4, component

Este el mi código que quiero pasar a **Javascript**, ya que **Vue** no usa `DOM`, se que document lo remplazare con un "mounted( )"

Código.:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {  
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active'); 
   }); 
});
```

Ayuda ,  ya probé instalando `JQuery` por npm pero se adueña de manera global en todo el proyecto, y solo quiero usarlo en un componente

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que hace este codigo? tal vez es mas facil hacerlo sin copiar el codigo, solamente sabiendo que hace?

Comment: Por que necesitas jquery? eso lo puedes manejar desde vue en el evento clic del elemento @click= toggleSideBar=!toggleSideBar por ejemplo y luego con v-show=toggleSideBar  manejas la visibilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Con Vue lo puedes hacer de una manera muy sencilla. No necesitas jQuery.
Si estás archivos .vue lo que necesitas es algo así:

`

```
<template>
   <div class="sidebar" v-class="{ active: isNavBarActive }"></div>
   <button @click="isNavBarActive = !isNavBarActive"></button>
</template>
```

`

`

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isNavBarActive: false
    }
  }
}
```

`

La directiva v-class coloca una clase según una sentencia. En este caso si isNavBarActive es true entones coloca la clase active y si es false la quita.
Y con en el @click estamos haciéndole un toggle a esa variable.